# Merging two DataFrames based on Conditions

Tags: python, dataframe

I want to merge two DataFrames based on matching the conditions of fact_date and scen between the two dataframes and then add the altdate column to the second dataframe.

The first dataframe looks like the following:

```
          fact_date   scen altdate
0        2008-08-18   -1  2008-08-25
1        2008-08-18    0  2008-08-18
2        2008-08-18    1  2008-08-15
3        2008-08-18    2  2008-08-14
4        2008-08-18    3  2008-08-13
5        2008-08-18    4  2008-08-12
6        2008-08-18    5  2008-08-11
7        2008-08-18    6  2008-08-08
8        2008-08-18    7  2008-08-07
9        2008-08-18    8  2008-08-06
...
```

The second dataframe looks like the following:

```
          fact_date  flag       scen  values
0        2008-08-18     0       -1   462456.29
1        2008-08-18     0        0  1119881.78
2        2008-08-18     0        1  1922320.74
3        2008-08-18     0        2  3559026.11
4        2008-08-18     0        3  3510447.61
5        2008-08-18     0        4  4873269.42
6        2008-08-18     0        5  5098557.55
7        2008-08-18     0        6  4610888.45
8        2008-08-18     0        7  4090821.69
9        2008-08-18     0        8  4219340.84
...
```

The output should look like the follwoing:

```
          fact_date  flag       scen  values     altdate
0        2008-08-18     0       -1   462456.29   2008-08-25
1        2008-08-18     0        0  1119881.78   2008-08-18
2        2008-08-18     0        1  1922320.74   2008-08-15
3        2008-08-18     0        2  3559026.11   2008-08-14
4        2008-08-18     0        3  3510447.61   2008-08-13
5        2008-08-18     0        4  4873269.42   2008-08-12
6        2008-08-18     0        5  5098557.55   2008-08-11
7        2008-08-18     0        6  4610888.45   2008-08-08
8        2008-08-18     0        7  4090821.69   2008-08-07
9        2008-08-18     0        8  4219340.84   2008-08-06
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try

```
df2.merge(df1, on=['fact_date', 'scen'])
```

which returns

```
    fact_date  flag  scen      values     altdate
0  2008-08-18     0    -1   462456.29  2008-08-25
1  2008-08-18     0     0  1119881.78  2008-08-18
2  2008-08-18     0     1  1922320.74  2008-08-15
3  2008-08-18     0     2  3559026.11  2008-08-14
4  2008-08-18     0     3  3510447.61  2008-08-13
5  2008-08-18     0     4  4873269.42  2008-08-12
6  2008-08-18     0     5  5098557.55  2008-08-11
7  2008-08-18     0     6  4610888.45  2008-08-08
8  2008-08-18     0     7  4090821.69  2008-08-07
9  2008-08-18     0     8  4219340.84  2008-08-06
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are saying, but i think you just want a join. If you are using Pandas it should be like this:

```
df2 = df2.join(df1,on=['fact_date','scen'],how='left')
```

Hope this helps.